# Group_by and having vs Joins when table is self joined 5-6 times

Tags: database-design, performance, join, database-agnostic

Now the situation due to which this question came to me. 
Schema is

```
    Table User_Read_Book
       user_id | book_id
```

Now I want to get users who have read certain books. Say give me users who have read book number 1 and 2. Number of books to test can go upto 10.

First query I wrote :

```
Select user_id from User_Read_Book Where book_id In (1,2) Group by user_id Having count(book_id) = 2
```

Second query:

```
Select  user_id from User_Read_Book as U join User_Read_Book as U1 On
 U.user_id = U1.user_id And U1.book_id = 1 where U.book_id = 2
```

As said in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/621891 that prefer joins in case of group by and having I did the second query.

But my question is which is better query when number to match up are large. Say when you have to find users who have read 7 books

```
   Having Count(book_id) = 7
   or
   6 joins to the same table.
```

I know this question is best answered when tested on large and real time data. 
Still what is the opinion of experts on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With 7 books, my guess would be that 7 joins is faster than `GROUP BY / HAVING`.

But it depends on the DBMS, the version, the optimizer's settings, the database settings, the RAM you have, the hard disks' performance, the indexes fragmentation, the overall pressure on the server and possibly several other parameters. Even more, even all the previous are set still, it depends on your data (and its distribution) and the specific parameters of the query. For example, if the 7 books are the 7 books of Harry Potter and all your users are Harry Potter's fans, then the `GROUP BY/HAVING` may be faster.

Plus, you shouldn't trust others, however experts they may (look to) be, when you can test. Why don't you test - with your data in your server and your settings - the performance of both ways, using variable number of books (and titles)?

Check also this question (with a similar query) where several other (more than 10) ways are shown (and benchmarked in PostgrSQL): [How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation)

---

**UPDATE**

**explanation of the "guess" that 7 Joins are usually better than `GROUP BY / HAVING`:**

Imagine you have a million users and about a million books. Now, on average, a user has read 100 books (in your database, totally fictional data and distribution). So, the table has about 100M rows.

Now, the `GROUP BY` query would have something like `WHERE book_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)`. Lets assume that `book_id=1` is the most popular (the Bible) and has about 100K readers and the other 6 are not so popular, having between 100 to 1000 readers each. This would limit the rows to be grouped to something between 100K and 106K. That translates (roughly) to the SQL engine reading 106K data from the proper index and then doing the `GROUP BY user_id`. So, (it will probably choose to use the `(user_id, book_id)` index), and it will do about 100K calculations of the `COUNT(book_id)` - and reject anyone that is not `7`.

In the 7 `JOIN` query, it has more options. The optimizer may choose to use the other index, the `(book_id, user_id)` one. Imagine "taking out" 7 smaller parts of this big index, the `(1, user_id)` part (remember: 100K data (user_ids) in it), the `(2, user_id)` part (less than 1000 data in here), ..., up to the `(7, user_id)` part (less than 1000 data in here, too). So now, it has to somehow combine those 7 index-parts (which is just 7 lists of userids) and find which userids are in ALL of the 7 lists. There are some clever algorithms that do just that, **without** having to do a whole reading (full scan) of the 7 lists. Just notice that even a dumb algorithm that combines first the 6 smaller lists, may end up with only a handful of userids (lets say just 1). To find if this 1 user_id is in the big (first) list, only a binary search is needed (remember it's not really a list, it's an index and that's what is good about indexes, you can search fast in them). So, even if there are only 100 user_ids, 100 searches in the big 100K list/index will only need less than 100*17 operation ( `log(100K) ~= 17` ). Which is 1700 operations, much less than the `GROUP BY` 100K operations. And no `COUNT(*)` is needed.

Therefore, with the Joins, if most books are not very popular (or just one book and we get lucky), the query will be quite efficient because it will have to look at the index on a very small number of places.
(Another thought is that with the Group By method, the query has calculated - before rejecting them - how many books have read all those users that have read 1 or 2 or ... or 6 books. But we don't care if they read 1 or 6. We just need to know if they have read all 7 !)

The situation is different off course if all the 7 chosen books are very popular. Now, the 7 index parts are all big and combining them may be less efficient than using the `GROUP BY` method which uses only one pass at one index.
(And the other thought says that the Group By is efficient now because almost all Count calculations will be a `7`, so a very small number of calculations is wasted)

Comment: I am using Postgresql. So GROUP BY works better if the data is related and more meaningful. Random data makes it slow. Right?

Comment: No, randomness is not the issue here (if I understand what you mean). Updated the answer.

Comment: So it depends upon popularity and size of the individual ids data. That is an awesome explanation. Thanks

Comment: @codecool: Yeah, data distribution can affect performance.

Comment: Also note that if you want to find readers that have read **at least 4 - out of 7** books, then the `GROUP BY` method is almost the only way to go.

Comment: Especially if one of the 7 books is seldom read, the optimizer can guess this by statistics on the book_id column and start with this selection as the first step. If it only gets 100 hits from there, it will probably only do a fast index access for these 100 and the other book_ids (which will be blazing fast if there also is an index on user_id,book_id)

Answer (score 2):

### Performance

It depends A LOT on the actual data (are there many people having read a few books each, or a few people having read many books), skewing (are there some power-readers?) and the books which you query - like ypercube mentioned the bible.

And this is before the optimizer really sets in and decides to completely rewrite your query because it fathoms something might be faster....

In principle the multiple Joins will most probably either do multiple selects on the Table, each time getting a set of Users for each book and then do an intersect between these sets to find the users present in all sets. Or it will first select all users for one book and when the resulting list is small enough and the right index is present the query will use the index to check each of the individual users from the first list for all books they have read.

The Group-By/Having clause will most probably result in either a huge number of index accesses for all rows which contain one of the books and then group and count them. Or for a big number of books will more likely result in a full table scan and just tally up all relevant rows resulting in the user list.

So my guess would be - if you expect a big number of users in the result-list and are searching for a combination of books which very many of your users have read, a full table scan will probably be faster in IO (the memory consumption should be negligible...) --
If on the other hand you have rather special and seldom read books in your list, and/or the resulting set of hits will be a very small number of users, the multiple JOIN access is probably faster if the optimizer can quickly scale it down and doesn't need as many IO accesses...

Overall the prevalent factor in performance will most likely be the number of Disk-Reads and the actual locations of these reads (non-consecutive) and there a huge number of index-accesses could kill your performance, even if the algorithm with multiple joins should in theory be faster.

**BUT** as ypercube said the only right way to sort this out is to run benchmarks on actual data (not staged data, but data which is very close to your real/expected customer data)

### Usability / Maintainability

If you ask me what I would use in actual production code? Clearly the only viable option is the GROUP BY/HAVING alternative, since it is flexible (You can just bind an array/list as the variable and search for a random number of books) and you can also search for 5 out of 7 and so on. With the join solution you would have 7 different queries in your code each for a number of books... and highly unflexible for other use-cases

Furthermore when written in Code the GROUP BY/HAVING solution is highly idiomatic. With a bit clearer comments and formatting, any programmer will imediatly understand the query. The SELF-JOIN monstrosity will be a bit harder to understand and maintain...

Comment: I wouldn't call it a monstrosity and it can be easily built with dynamic SQL.